# IIS Express Blocks VS 2010SP1 Builds

Tags: iis-express, visual-studio-2010

After several build / debug cycles, IIS Express (both 7.5 and 8.0RC) start to block builds of the project in VS 2010SP1.

The build will hang indefinitely until I terminate IIS Express.

Is there a fix/workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding a pre-build event to kill IIS Express if it is running.

> taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq iisexpress.exe"

**UPDATE**

This solution helps but is not perfect.  Sometimes the build will fail with an error message that the IIS Express process could not be terminated.  Still hoping for a better solution...