# Visual Studio Pre-Build Event: Batch File Exit Code is -1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, batch-file, exit-code

In order to work around the issue [IIS Express Blocks VS 2010SP1 Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445157/iis-express-blocks-vs-2010sp1-builds) I have created a simple batch file

```
taskkill /IM iisexpress.exe
exit 0
```

and set that batch file as a pre-build event.

If IIS Express is actually running, it works great.  However, if IIS Express is *not* running the build fails with the following output:

> The process "iisexpress.exe" not found.
>   The command "E:\Software\Util\KillIisExpress.bat" exited with code -1.

If instead of the batch file I use the taskkill command as the pre-build event, the error changes to

> The command "taskkill /IM iisexpress.exe" exited with code 128.

How can I modify the batch file so that, no matter what exit code taskkill returns, the batch file returns with an exit code of 0 so that the VS build succeeds?

Comment: If you directly run `taskkill` instead of using `call taskkill` and there is no `iisexpress.exe` running, taskkill will exit non-zero directly, always bypassing your `exit 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq iisexpress.exe"
```

which will output an info message if iisexpress.exe isn't running, but will return 0.  You don't need the batch file with this, just add the command as the Pre-Build Event Command Line.